# Save multiple selected listbox Item to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a listbox, I want to save all the selected items in different rows in database, please how will I do it, I tried

```
foreach (ListItem item in comboGroup.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                grp.username = comboUserName3.SelectedValue.ToString();
                string selectedItem = item.Value.ToString();
                int val = int.Parse(selectedItem);
                grp.groupid = val;
                //grp.iscurrent = true;
                grp.dateadded = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        db.group_user.Add(grp);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

but its only saving the last selected item

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @ADyson thanks alot, I see it now, its working

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu no problem, please remember to mark the best answer as "accepted" (you may have to wait until your question is a few more minutes old) - thanks. (You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer so it turns green).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line db.group_user.Add(grp); seems to be outside the for loop. You are overriding the values while looping each time. So at the end, when it exits the loop, it is left with just the last value.

Modify the code to,

```
foreach (ListItem item in comboGroup.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            grp.username = comboUserName3.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string selectedItem = item.Value.ToString();
            int val = int.Parse(selectedItem);
            grp.groupid = val;
            //grp.iscurrent = true;
            grp.dateadded = DateTime.Now;
            db.group_user.Add(grp);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't do the "add" until after you've left the loop. So it just runs once, and uses the value of `grp` as it was the last time the loop executed. You need to do one "Add" for each item (because each "add" creates a single row), so essentially the "add" must be inside the loop and you also ought to declare `grp` as a fresh object every time. (SaveChanges can stay outside the loop, if you're wondering).

```
foreach (ListItem item in comboGroup.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        var grp = new group_user();
        grp.username = comboUserName3.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string selectedItem = item.Value.ToString();
        int val = int.Parse(selectedItem);
        grp.groupid = val;
        //grp.iscurrent = true;
        grp.dateadded = DateTime.Now;
        db.group_user.Add(grp);
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```